# Store output from odeint stiff equation solver

Tags: c++, ode, odeint

I was wondering if there was a way to store the output of the following [code](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/stiff_system.cpp) into a boost matrix or vector.

```
size_t num_of_steps = integrate_const( make_dense_output< rosenbrock4< double > >( 1.0e-6 , 1.0e-6 ) ,
        make_pair( stiff_system() , stiff_system_jacobi() ) ,
        x , 0.0 , 50.0 , 0.01 ,cout << phoenix::arg_names::arg2 << " " << phoenix::arg_names::arg1[0] << "\n" );
```

The lines 94-97 above passes cout << "" << endl statements into a function as arguments. These statements print the results. I haven't found a way to store the results by modifying these passed statements.

Comment: are you aware of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) concept?

Comment: I wasn't but I just gave it a cursory reading. I don't think there's a way to shorten the linked code while at the same time making the results reproducible. Do you have any suggested edit?

Comment: From what I have read giving a look at your code, I see that you are simply performing a `cout << ` with different data types, which sounds to be an issue when you would want to save that data instead of displaying it. Each call of `cout << T` calls an `std::ostream& operator <<` with `T` as an argument. The question is - is saving your data to `vector` or `matrix` is mandatory? Is there something wrong with `std::stringstream`? It can surely behave like a container in some ways

Comment: Using stringstream appears to store the whole output into a single stringstream. I need to store output at periodic intervals and separately on them.

Comment: Whats wrong with having a delimeter?

Comment: Yes , that would work. But I found another solve that could be more efficient. Thanks. I will put it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The vector x stores the state values at different times so simple assignment statements, like

```
 a[0] = x[0];
```

where a[0] is the vector you want to store your output in, will work.